# Set basePath in Swagger 2.x with swagger-jaxrs2 and openapi-configuration.yaml file

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, swagger-2.0

How can I set the basepath in Swagger 2.x?

The application is built against JaxRS and Wildfly. Swagger is configured using the auto configuration from swagger-jaxrs2 and an openapi-configuration.yaml file.

I can open swagger-ui and browse the api documentation but when I want to "try it out", the requests are not going to the right url because the jboss context root is missing. How can I add this context root to the generated openapi.json?

I read in the documentation that I can extend Application and configure swagger programmatically but I would prefer it if the configuration can stay in maven. It is a multi module project so I would like to avoid duplicate code and keep the setup process simple for new modules. Is this possible?

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
<context-root>/app-root</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

openapi-configuration.yaml (filled with maven resource filtering):

```
resourcePackages:
  - ${project.groupId}
prettyPrint: true
cacheTTL: 0
openAPI:
  info:
    version: ${project.version}
    title: ${project.name}
    description: ${project.description}
    contact:
      email: contact@email.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Server Locations to your openapi.yaml. It has to look like this:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  version: ${project.version}
  title: ${project.name}
servers:
  url: /app-root
paths:
```

The server Url can be replaced with an variable which is filled by maven.

Comment: Actually I already tried adding that to my openapi-configuration.yaml but it is not included in my openapi.yaml file.

Comment: OK, it did work but `- url` only needs to be indented by 2 spaces.